# How to Sort complex JSON data code & value pair in React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have below JSON data & I need to sort the values which are code & value pairs and need display sorted values in UI

```
const Data=
 {
"actions": {   
"canUpdateXyz": true  
},
"criteria": [
{   
  "CriteriaId" : 123
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "CCode",
    "value": "C Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "123456"
  ]
},
{
  "CriteriaId" : 234
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "BCode",
    "value": "B Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "R"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
},
{
  //no CriteriaId as its newly added in UI and yet to save to database
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ACode",
    "value": "A Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
},
{
  //no CriteriaId as its newly added in UI and yet to save to database
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ZCode",
    "value": "Z Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
}
],
"outcome": {
"code": "create",
"value": "Always create"
},
"unlessCriteria": []
}
```

& I need to do Sort By processType, criteriaType.

after sorting JSON data should be

```
 const Data=
 {
"actions": {
"canUpdateAbc": true,
"canUpdateXyz": true  
},
"criteria": [
{
  //no CriteriaId as its newly added in UI and yet to save to database
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ACode",
    "value": "A Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
},
{   
  "CriteriaId" : 123
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "CCode",
    "value": "C Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "123456"
  ]
},
{
  //no CriteriaId as its newly added in UI and yet to save to database
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "ZCode",
    "value": "Z Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "C"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
},
{
  "CriteriaId" : 234
  "criteriaType": {
    "code": "BCode",
    "value": "B Code"
  },
  "processType": {
    "code": "PType",
    "value": "R"
  },
  "values": [
    "567890"
  ]
} 
],
"outcome": {
"code": "create",
"value": "Always create"
},
"unlessCriteria": []
}
```

I have tried using loadash orderBy...

```
{orderBy(
          Data.criteria,
          [(criterion) => criterion.processType?.value, (criterion) => criterion.criteriaType?.value],
          ['asc']
        )?.map((criteriaItem, criteriaItemIndex) => (
          <div key={`criteria-${criteriaItem?.criteriaType?.code}`}>
            {console.log('test', criteriaItem)}
         </div>
```

& Its not working for newly added items.

How to achieve in Reactjs-Typescript?